# scrolling not working for name tag in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

I have read and tried a number of solutions to scrolling down a iframe but none of them is working for me.  This is the javascript function were a timer callback done by jquery.js.  When the input file is changed, I regenerated the page (src="pp_ContactRangesPanel.php?sc=terra&path=/var/www/html/java_clocks/terra/terra_aos_times&filter=N;#target") and the updated the iframe via reload().  I then try to scroll to the name="target" line in the iframe but it never moves.  There is a "jump to target line" button at the top of the input web page and it jumps to the target line ok, so I know the tag is there there after the reload.  This is the javascript part that reloads the page and should scroll to target line.

```
        // new mtime vs. last mtime test
        if ($aPath[$currentFile][2] != $aPath[$currentFile][3]) {
            $aPath[$currentFile][3] = $aPath[$currentFile][2];

            // read in file again and re-populate mission table
            var obj = document.getElementById($aPath[$currentFile][0]);
            obj.contentWindow.location.reload();

            var doc = (obj.contentDocument)? obj.contentDocument: obj.contentWindow.document;
            var anchors = doc.getElementsByName('target');

            // got target line?
            if (0 < anchors.length)
            {
                doc.scrollTo(0, anchors[0].offsetTop);
            }
        }
```

Some over head:

1. The iframe height was set to 257 when the 3 rows of iframes were created.
2. This iframe is on the second row.
3. The anchors[0].offsetTop returned is 834 which makes makes sense since the src web page generated has 80 lines in it.
4. For my test I either scrolled to the top or bottom of the page before touching the input file to kick off the reload.

So any ideas why doesn't it script to target line?

Comment: Have you tried to scroll `html` element instead of `document`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around for the scrolling problem.  Instead of doing the obj.contentWindow.location.reload() command which doesn't appear to include the #target part, I reset the src attribute to its self.  Since the original src string (ex. "pp_ContactRangesPanel.php?sc=aqua&path=/var/www/html/java_clocks/aqua/aqua_aos_times&filter=N;#target") contains "#target" at the end of the string, the iframe scrolls to it when the page is regenerated.  It still would be nice to know what was wrong with the scrollTo command.

```
// read in file again and re-populate mission table
var obj = document.getElementById($aPath[$currentFile][0]);
// Note: the obj.contentWindow.location.reload(); way does not remember the #target 
// part so I am resetting the src to the orginal src value thereby forcing it a reload by 
// appending NULL to the end of the string.  I could have gotten the string obj.src and 
// used that, but this seems cleaner.
obj.src += '';
```